# Parse yaws get query

Tags: erlang, get, yaws

This crashed

```
out(A) ->
    io:format("~wqqq12", yaws_api:queryvar(A, "id"), yaws_api:parse_query(A)),
```

with this

```
Reason: {function_clause,
            [{io,request,
                 ["~wqqq12",{format,undefined,[{"id","F1D79543E9E6583B"}]}]},
```

But it's clear that "id" is present in the get query. Why can't it parse it?

edited:

And query: *.yaws?id=F1D79543E9E6583B

edited2:

sorry for misleading, but i use format for send values to browser, its intended error. I'm intersted in why second argument in format becomes "undefined".

Comment: Ok, now i do so: proplists:lookup("id", yaws_api:parse_query(A)). And all working fine, but for what standing queryvar??

Answer (score 3):

You are calling io:format the wrong way. The correct is:

```
io:format(Format, ListOfParams)
```

Where `Format` is a String and `ListOfParams` is a list of terms to be used in your format.

Check the [io:format/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-2) manual for more details.